# ipad 2 not opening

Tags: ios, ipad, software-update

Yesterday I did an update on IOS that was available in my iPad 2 (I think it was 9.3.2). After that it's asking me to configure and take some steps to reopen but after trying a while it says that the activation server is not available and won't open. Not even the home page.

I have done an update before without problems. What can I do?

Comment: wait it out, it's busy. You ought to be able to get past the iCloud sign in quite quickly. It times out in a few minutes & then everything else will be OK until next attempt

Comment: This is a known issue mostly affecting iPad 2 models.  There is a workaround:  https://discussions.apple.com/message/29954951#29954951

Comment: @Allan Could you edit the post to show a picture of the error? Without some details this likely will get closed again as duplicate since connecting to iTunes and running a restore/update manually is something that's likely been covered here multiple times...

Comment: @bmike  I'll see if I can find one.  This is a new error related to 9.3 and I fixed it for a relative just last night.  Suffice to say, I don't have the iPad with the error at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Apple has pulled the update (for that model, perhaps). Here are steps to proceed until an update to the update is released:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206203

Thanks to The Loop for the details on this:

- http://www.loopinsight.com/2016/03/24/apple-pausing-ios-9-3-updates-for-ipad-2/
- http://www.imore.com/apple-working-ios-93-fix-older-iphone-ipad

---

Sooner than I expected a new build is out:

- http://9to5mac.com/2016/03/24/apple-releases-new-build-of-ios-9-3-for-users-of-older-ios-devices-affected-by-bricking-bug/

> iPad 2 users can update to the new firmware update by plugging their iPad into iTunes if it’s in a bricked state or by heading into Settings and navigating to the software update menu and updating like they normally would.